# How to detect shape collision - Android

Tags: android, collision-detection

I would like to detect collisions between shapes dynamically drawn on a canvas (SurfaceView) for an Android game.

I can easily use intersect method of Rect or RectF objects but the result is not very good (see picture below where I have a "false" detection).

[image]

I don't want to use Bitmap so it's impossible to use the "pixel perfect" method.

Do you know a way to do this for circle, rect, triangle and other basic shapes intersection ?

Thx for help ;)

Comment: Take a look for collision detection algorithms such as AABB and OBB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a good collision detection you have to create your own models behind. In those models you specify the conditions that two objects colide.

For example, a circle is described by the center position and by the radius. A square is described by the left down corner and by the edge length.

You don' t have to describe all possible poligons, you can use the so called bounding boxes, meaning that, for a complex random poligon you can use a square or whathever shape fits it best(also you can use multiple shapes for a single object).

After you have the objects in mind you compute the condition that each one of them will colide with all other shapes including itself.

In your example The sphere and the square colides if the distance between any corner of the square is greater than the circle's radius.

Here you can read more http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/13/basic-collision-detection-in-2d-part-1/

This problem can get very complex, keep it simple if you want something simple.

Comment: I think your solution is the best but it seems to be difficult to find an algorithm enough generic for all kind of shape... I should probably change my mind and use Bitmap with pixel perfect algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To know if a polygon in 2d is colliding with a circle, you can test, for each of its lines, where is the point on the line that is closest to the center of the circle ([this might help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation)).

Then, check if the point you found is between to two corners that make the line - that is, that the point is actually on the line, and not just on its continuation - and if the distance of that point to the center of the circle is smaller or equal to the radius of the circle. If both are true for any of the lines of the polygon, you have a collusion. You also have to check for the edge cases where the corners of the polygon might be in, or touching the circle.

For two circles, this is easier. Check the distance between the centers, and compare it to the sum of their radiuses. If the distance is smaller or equal to the sum, you have a collusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a directly applicable method I use in my own game to detect circle and rectangle intersection. It takes the ball (which is a view in this case) and the rectangle (also a view) to be checked for collision with the ball as parameters. You can put the method in a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and set the interval you want the circle and rectangle to be checked for collision.

Here is the method:

```
public boolean intersects(BallView ball, Rectangle rect) {
        boolean intersects = false;
        if (ball.getX() + ball.getR() >= rect.getTheLeft() &&
            ball.getX() - ball.getR() <= rect.getTheRight() &&
            ball.getY() + ball.getR() <= rect.getTheBottom() &&
            ball.getY() - ball.getR() >= rect.getTheTop())
        {
            intersects = true;
        }

        return intersects;

    }
```

`getR()` gets the circle's radius

`getX()` gets the center of the circle's X position value

`getTheLeft()` gets the rectangle's left X value

`getTheRight()` gets the rectangle's right X value

`getTheTop()` gets the rectangle's top Y value

`getTheBottom()` gets the rectangle's bottom Y value

If you can't directly use this method in your code you can still conjecture the logic it entails to implement it where it would work for you. It detects all collisions without using pseudo-collision detection like a collision box for the circle.

Good luck! And if you have any questions feel free to ask, I'm here to help!